# Hide Asus power saving tab

Tags: motherboard

I have Windows 8.1 with an Asus H87M-Plus motherboard. In the bottom-right hand corner of the screen there is a tab that if you click on it will bring up some power saving options (Auto Mode, High Performance Mode, Power Saving Mode, Away Mode). When it hides itself it is difficult to see. However, the computer is connected to a large LCD and if I'm playing a video I can see a tiny little white spot in the corner.

I think these tabs are coming from Asus AI Suite 3 as the icons look the same as when I go to the EPU tab in that utility. However, I see no options or settings to remove them in the utility. Maybe somewhere in the bios?

I spent 20 minutes waiting for tech support before I gave up.

Comment: Why not just uninstall all the Asus bloatware via Add/Remove programs?

Comment: I was thinking about that. Probably a good idea. Was hoping there would be a solution without doing that.

Comment: Yeah, it was just one part of the Suite that was causing it. I was able to remove just that part and keep the rest.

Comment: @John If you were able to solve the problem, you can answer your own question so that others can easily find the solution later.

Comment: I wasn't really able to solve the problem as I specified in the question. I couldn't figure out how to hide it. I could only remove it. I'd still be interested if someone can figure out how to hide it (in case I accidentally re-install the suite in the future).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Please refrain from making biased and defamatory comments on subject in which you are uninformed. AI Suite and the associated utilities are extremely useful and provide features that Windows does not. For instance AI Suite allowed me to automatically overclock my i7-5960X from 3.0GHz to 4.6GHz without having to do anything but press a button. Some of the other so-called "bloatware" allows me to increase the power on the USB ports so I can charge multiple devices, including an iPad Air 2 and iPhone. In addition I was able to increase the speed of my USB 3 ports by about 20-40%.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the AI Suite III tray icon (probably hidden) and deselect "ASUS mini bar". Voila! It will fade away slowly. Such a nice way to die! Stupid annoying widget"

Source: http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/29578-get-rid-of-asus-ai-suite-widget/

Comment: Thank you for the intelligent, useful answer. This worked perfectly.